# Django - Is this solution DRY or is there a better way to model these profile classes and subclasses?

Tags: python, django, django-models, dry, user-profile

Basically, I have the following requirements:

- A user has a personal user profile
- An organisation can have a staff profile
- The staff profile can be independent or link to a user
- The organisation can edit the staff profile without changing the users' personal user profile
- A user changing their personal user profile wouldn't affect an organisations staff profile of the user
- A user can be staff at multiple organisations (and hence have multiple staff profiles)
- A user doesn't have to be staff

**Currently I have the following classes** *(Irrelevant fields removed for simplicity)*

*profiles.models.py*

```
class Profile(TimeStampMixin):
   title    = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=Title.choices, blank=True)
   forename = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
   surname  = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)


class UserProfile(Profile):
   user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="profile", on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class StaffProfile(Profile):
   user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, blank=True, db_index=True, related_name="staff_profiles")
```

*organisations.models.py*

```
class Organisation(TimeStampMixin):
   staff = models.ManyToManyField('profiles.StaffProfile', blank=True, related_name="organisations")
```

What I'm wondering is whether this solution is DRY and whether it's the best way of dealing with the requirements?

The reason I'm not sure is because I've contemplated having *StaffProfile* extend *UserProfile* instead of *Profile* and changing the *OneToOneField* in *UserProfile* to a *ForeignKey* Field however this seems like it would complicate finding a User's personal profile from their staff profile. Unless I change the *related_name* by setting *related_name* through a function so that in *UserProfile* it equals "profile" and in *StaffProfile* it equals "staff_profiles"? However, is this just over-engineering at this point?

Also as a staff profile doesn't have to have a user associated with it, is this the best way to model a staff profile or is there a better way to link a user to a staff profile later? E.g. Have another class to link a user to the staff profile if needed? I feel like this would again just add complexity / be over-engineered though...

If you could give me your thoughts on the problem and my solution I'd be greatly appreciative!

Thanks in advance for any help,

*GoingRoundInCircles*

Comment: The way you implement StaffProfile to Organisation as a many-to-many relation, a user would have the _same_ staff profile at every organisation they belong to. Is this intended?

Comment: @cemper93 - That's a great spot! It was like that because originally I was going to have one profile to one user and that would be it. However, I wanted the organisation to be able to have control over the staff's profile so that the staff member couldn't alter their details maliciously hence my current solution of having staff profiles in addition to a user profile... (there isn't a way to make that DRYer is there?)

So I should link the organisation via a ForeignKey in the StaffProfile class instead right? Or do you see a better alternative given the requirements? Thanks for spotting that!

Comment: I think your model code doesn't have any problems with "DRY-ness", although that's not really a proper term to talk about model architecture anyway. You should be thinking about database normalization instead, which is a related topic, but not the same. In any case, yes, your suggested fix will work.

Comment: @cemper93 - Sorry, yes normalization is what I meant in my previous comment; I just got confused. Do you think my solution is the right way to deal with the problem or is there a better way to normalize the data? As in theory the profile data should be the same everywhere for a given user but I don't know how I would stop malicious alters to the data and who I would allow/disallow editing the data from all the organisations the user is a staff member at as well as the user themselves... hence why I thought to have one staff profile per organisation but then it's a lot of duplicated data.

Comment: @cemper93 - continuing on with my last comment, the other issue of course is that a staff profile doesn't have to have a user attached to it so I couldn't just give responsibility of the data to the user for example as their may not even be one. The profile may have just been created by the organisation itself. And in any case, the user could still corrupt their data which wouldn't be good for the organisation.

Comment: These sound like domain modeling problems, which I cannot help you with. The right answer to all your questions is "as best suits your application's and customer's needs".

Comment: @cemper93 Aaah I see, no worries! Thank you for all of your help! And pointing me in the right direction!